# Pause and unpause loop in javascript within an async function

Tags: javascript

I have an async function that has a loop that I need to be able to pause or unpause it. This is what I have so far.

I use a flag to pause the flow:

```
let flag = true;

function flag_func() {
    flag = !flag;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    function sleep(ms) {
        while (!flag) {
            //...waiting.. but infinite loop 
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function show_simulation(data) {
        document.getElementById("solve-button").outerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" id='pause-button' onclick='flag_func()' class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\">Pause</button>";
        //simulation
        if (data.length === 0) {
            console.log('stuff')
        } else {
            let i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                await sleep(40);
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that is being paused, but due the `while` block the flow, I can't unpause the `for` loop.

Any idea about how I can solve this?

Comment: @bigless I know that, I said it in the question

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, this approach won't work. the while(!flag){...} will continue running forever, and because JS is single threaded that means that no other code will ever run. Why do you need the while(!flag) loop? If we know the purpose, we might be able to figure out a different solution.

Comment: @PunDefeated, was my approach to pause the loop

Comment: @exsnake ah okay, so you’re looking for something to replace the sleep function, not the while(!flag) ?

Comment: @PunDefeated I'm looking for something to replace the while, something like 'wait the button to be pressed'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a nice use case for async iterables. It involves a bit of boilerplate to create your async list, but then the code is much nicer. Basically you would have:

```
import AsyncList from './async-list.js'

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function f(data) {
  const list = new AsyncList(data);

  document.getElementById("btn-toggle").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (list.paused) {
      this.textContent = "Pause";
      list.resume();
    } else {
      this.textContent = "Resume";
      list.pause()
    }
  })


  for await (let item of list) {
    console.log(item)
    await sleep(1000);
  }
  console.log("end of loop")
}

f([10, "hello", 1029, 90, 80, 209, 44])
```

A possible implementation of `AsyncList` could be:

```
export default class AsyncList {
  constructor(array) {
    // shallow copy
    this._array = array.slice();

    this._index = 0;
    this._length = this._array.length;
    this.paused = false;
    this._resume = () => {}; // noop, in case `resume` is called before `pause`
  }

  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return this;
  }

  pause() {
    this.paused = true;
  }

  resume() {
    this.paused = false;
    this._resume();
  }

  next() {
    if (this._index < this._length) {
      const value = this._array[this._index++];

      if (this.paused) {
        return new Promise(r => this._resume = r.bind(null, { value }))
      }

      return Promise.resolve({ value })
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
    }
  }
}
```

Just to give to you the idea, you could also encapsulate the private properties, and check more scenarios (here I assume `data` is an array, for example, not just an iterable).

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace:

```
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        await sleep(40);
        // do stuff
    }
```

...with...

```
    let i = 0;
    const doStuff = () => {
      // do stuff

      if (++i < data.length) {
        setTimeout(doStuff, 40);
      }
    };

    setTimeout(doStuff, 40);
```

Comment: have you noticed this: `async function show_simulation(data) {` ? it's an async function, thus the await keyword.

Comment: I noticed. My point was I didn't see any good reason to be using async/await.